# How to best write a classes' methods to update the status of an object

Tags: php, oop, object

I have two types of objects, call them Object1, and Object2. Whenever i make CRUD changes to these objects I record the changes in a special "status" table. I am writing out the classes for handling each type of object and have come to dealing with the statuses. Right now I have a function that the status data is passed to along with the type of object, and then it makes the necessary DB inserts, however I want to write this into the classes somehow, and am unsure of the best practice.

Should I create a third object for the statuses, should I create copy&paste methods in each object that do the same thing but with different hard coded wording? Can I extend both classes into a 3rd class to give them both the status method?

Best way to think of this problem is I have a Car and Truck object. Need to create a Garage method, but do I make it a method of the car and truck objects, or its own object, or what?

Answer (score -1):

IMOH(may i be wrong, i'm sure that i am), that is a good way to do this:

```
abstract class Base{
    protected $type = null;
    public function setStatus($status){
        $sql = "UPDATE SET `status` = '$status' FROM `table` WHERE `type` = '{$this->type}'";
    }
}
class One extends Base{
    protected $type = "type1";
}
class Two extends Base{
    protected $type = "type2";
}

$one = new One();
$one->setStatus('pending');
$two = new Two();
$two->setStatus('died');
```

And suddenly a wild static way appears

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static $type = null;
    public static function setStatus($status){
         $sql = sprintf("UPDATE SET `status` = '$status' FROM `table` WHERE `type` = '%s'",static::$type);
    }
}

class One extends Base{
    protected static $type = "one";
}

class Two extends Base{
    protected static $type = "two";
}

One::setStatus("idle");
Two::setStatus("dieing");
```

Comment: keep the business logic and data access layer separated. something i do is a static class but of many styles for many people i guess.

Comment: Static way would be a nice implementation too, i think now-a-day OOP is to much misused and misunderstood, I've seen lots of programmers using OOP like if it was a box with lots of functions.

Comment: no. i meant to say you could use the static class for the data access layer. its just something that i do because i wrote it that way awhile back.